# Redefine tab as 4 spaces in Gitlab CE

Tags: gitlab

See this huge identations is painful (for me). Is there a way to set tab size to 4 spaces.

This picture is taken from local Gitlab CE server with minimal customization. I think tabsize 8 spaces is default.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, gitlab uses browser CSS property tab-size which default value is 8.
There's a bug discussion about this here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2479
You can change gitlab CSS and you'll have what you want.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant.
The tab width can now be modified in Preferences -> Behavior page.

Answer (score 36):

Go to `Settings` → `Preferences` → `Behavior` and set `Tab width`.

Answer (score 3):

As of February 2021, this has not been addressed. One can check the current [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26768) for progress, but in the meantime, [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26768#note_215634043) comment on the thread offers a solution via creating a UserScript via [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) / [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) with this script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name GitLab Tab Size
// @version 1
// @include https://gitlab.com/*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

const TAB_SIZE = 2

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const styleElement = document.createElement('style')
  styleElement.innerHTML = `
    .diff-content, pre.code {
      -moz-tab-size: ${TAB_SIZE};
      tab-size: ${TAB_SIZE};
    }
  `
  document.head.appendChild(styleElement)
})
```

Credit to Brendan Gadd from that thread.